# watch mysql output w/ tabular columns

Tags: mysql, watch

how come when I run a mysql query and dump the results to stdout I get a pretty printed table
ie:

```
> mysql -e "describe <table>" <database>
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| col1       | varchar(36)  | NO   | PRI | NULL                |       |
| col2       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
| col3       | varchar(35)  | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
| col4       | varchar(35)  | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
| col5       | varchar(25)  | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| col6       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| col7       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| col8       | varchar(2)   | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| col9       | varchar(75)  | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| col10      | varchar(75)  | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| col11      | varchar(75)  | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| col12      | varchar(2)   | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| col13      | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| col14      | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| col15      | timestamp    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| col16      | timestamp    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| col17      | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

but if I dump a query out using the `watch` command, the tabular formatting goes away?

ie:

```
> watch -n 1 'mysql -e "describe <table>" <database>'


Every 1.0s: mysql -e "describe <table>" <database>  Mon Jun  9 12:08:54 2014

Field   Type    Null    Key     Default Extra
col1    varchar(36)     NO      PRI     NULL
col2    int(11) NO              NULL
col3            varchar(35)     NO              NULL
col4            varchar(35)     NO              NULL
col5       varchar(25)     YES             NULL
col6    varchar(255)    YES             NULL
col7            varchar(255)    YES             NULL
col8    varchar(2)      YES             NULL
col9            varchar(75)     YES             NULL
col10           varchar(75)     YES             NULL
col11   varchar(75)     YES             NULL
col12   varchar(2)      YES             NULL
col13  varchar(10)     YES             NULL
col14           varchar(20)     YES             NULL
col15           timestamp       NO              0000-00-00 00:00:00
col16           timestamp       NO              0000-00-00 00:00:00
col17           timestamp       YES             NULL
```

Can I get this back?  I tried playing w/ the --raw mode, but maybe I just missed the appropriate flag?

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the `-t` option.  MySQL's [Online Help](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html) says about `-t`:

> Display output in table format. This is the default for interactive use, but can be used to produce table output in batch mode.

So, when you run mysql from a prompt, you get the nice table format, but when you run in "batch mode" (for example, within a script, or in this case with `watch`), you don't get the formatting without using the `-t`.  What you want is probably some variation of this: `watch -n 1 'mysql -t -e "describe table" database'` which will return the nicely formatted tables.